# This package may not be fully compatible with your project

Tags: xamarin.forms, package, nuget

Hi Guys I am using visual studio 2017 to build Xamarin.Forms mobile app.
I installed **'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29'** Package from **NuGet packages** 
but i got this warning message :
**Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.**

How can I fix it ??

Comment: I have the same issue. Was you able to find a solution? I have tried to run the `dotnet remove package MY_PACKAGE_NAME` and it did not help. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to delete the reference and use the `HttpClient` declared in the `System.Net.Http` namespace.

Comment: Delete what reference, can you be more exact please? I am having the same error.

Comment: Man, your answer is not clear, add more information.